# Azure DevOps copying .env file to docker image

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I'm trying to build a pipeline with Azure DevOps and one of the tasks is to copy `.env` file into the docker image.

The `Dockerfile` looks like the below:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /nodebuild
ADD frontend /nodebuild

# Set environment variables from .env during node build
# so that the app uses the production location for static files
ADD .env /nodebuild
RUN export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs) && npm install && npm audit fix && npm run build
```

However, since `.env` contains my secret, I use [Secure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops) to store the file in Azure DevOps.

Now I'm trying to refer to this file from my Dockerfile, how could I do that?

Comment: This mechanism is designed for 
> Use the Secure Files library to store files such as signing certificates, Apple Provisioning Profiles, Android Keystore files, and SSH keys on the server without having to commit them to your source repository. Secure files are defined and managed in the Library tab in Azure Pipelines.
If you keep your secrets there you should not build them into Docker image.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej when the `.env` is a large file, I would recommend to manage it using Secure Files. Some processes in building image need the secret (for example, activities that are related to databases). At the end of the building process, we can remove `.env` from the imange. As for how to do it, see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a [download secure file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) task to download the .env file to the agent machine.

> Once downloaded, use the name value that is set on the task (or "Reference name" in the classic editor) to reference the path to the secure file on the agent machine. For example, if the task is given the name mySecureFile, its path can be referenced in the pipeline as $(mySecureFile.secureFilePath). Alternatively, downloaded secure files can be found in the directory given by $(Agent.TempDirectory)

Then you can add [Copy files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the .env file downloaded by above task to the docker build context. For below example:

```
steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download secure file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: .env

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
    Contents: .env
    TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

If folder `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` (ie. `c:\agent_work\1\s`) is the docker build context. You can then refer to .env file from your Dockerfile.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I've just done and it's working perfectly!